# vba modules on add-in not all available from other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

In the attached screenshot you will see that I have a .xlam add-in which is referred into the vba project. From the vba project I can access some modules via Intellisense - for example `GsccVbaLib.ProgressBarManager` - but not `GsccVbaLib.EnumManager`. However I can access via Intellisense all public procedures as expected by starting typing their names, for example for an enum I can start to type "AppCalc" and Intellisense kick in. If I type the name of the add-in "GsccVbaLib."  In Intellisense I can only see some of the modules but not all.
Does anyone know why this behaviour?   Is because I have added some modules whyle I had the VBA project opened rather than directly opening the xlam addin code and add new modules etc... Or is that the refereed add-in does not get updated in the project from where I refer it to ?

[image]

Comment: What do you want saying by not accessing modules (from other workbooks)? Do you mean procedures form those modules? If yes, how do you try running them?

Comment: I can run all procedures from the .xlam add-in; I do not understand why I do not always have intellisense for all fully qualified names. In Intellisense I see some modules but not all; however once typing I do have access to all procedures on Intellisense as long as I remember the name :-)

Comment: You tagged it VB6... but it seems to be only VBA?

Comment: I tagged both VBA and VB6 but yes is VBA; otehr than that any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be a simple intellisense cache refresh; I unticked the reference to the add-in, saved the workbook, opened and referenced again thea dd-in and now Intellisense display all public add-in members